# Observer http implemetation is wrong?

Tags: angular, observable

I would like to have a system like this ->

- component request ngrxstore to make api and subscribe to it to get the result
- my ngrxstore make the api call and subscribe to it to get the result
- my service do the api call and return an observable that everyone can observe

Here current implementation

Component =>

```
public CardMoved(){
     const params:load_item_params = {}

    let subscription = this._itemDetailsService.LoadItem(params).subscribe(data => {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

NGRX Store =>

```
LoadItem(params:API_TYPE.load_item_params) : Observable<any> {
    let observable$ = this._http.Post(UtilsService.apiServer + '/load_item', params);
    return observable$.pipe(
        map((data) => {
            return data;
        }),
    )
}
```

HTTP Service =>

```
public Post<T>(url: string, payload: any): Observable<T>;
public Post<T>(url, payload): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(url, payload, httpHeaders)
    .pipe(
        retry(MAX_RETRY)
    )
}
```

Everything looks fine, the problem I have, is that If I do not subscribe to the even in my component, the http call is not sent.

I believe I still haven't understand exactly how observable and all works, And I can't really understand why if I do not subscribe it do not make the api call

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lesson on Angular observables from the angular documentation.

**Basic usage and terms**

As a publisher, you create an Observable instance that defines a subscriber function. This is the function that is executed when a consumer calls the subscribe() method. The subscriber function defines how to obtain or generate values or messages to be published.

***To execute the observable you have created and begin receiving notifications, you call its subscribe() method***, passing an observer. This is a JavaScript object that defines the handlers for the notifications you receive. The subscribe() call returns a Subscription object that has an unsubscribe() method, which you call to stop receiving notifications.

https://angular.io/guide/observables